# How to take a substring with the endpoint being a carriage return and/or line feed?

Tags: powershell

How do I take a substring where I don't know the length of the thing I want, but I know that the end of it is a CR/LF?

I'm communicating with a server trying to extract some information. The start point of the substring is well defined, but the end point can be variable.  In other scripting languages, I'd expect there to be a `find()` command, but I haven't found one in PowerShell yet.  Most articles and SE questions refer to `Get-Content`, `substring`, and `Select-String`, with the intent to replace a CRLF rather than just find it.

The device I am communicating with has a telnet-like command structure.  It starts out with it's model as a prompt.  You can give it commands and it responds.  I'm trying to grab the hostname from it. This is what a prompt, command, and response look like in a terminal:

```
TSS-752>hostname
Host Name: ThisIsMyHostname

TSS-752>
```

I want to extract the hostname.  I came across `IndexOf()`, which seems to work like the find command I am looking for.  ":" is a good start point, and then I want to truncate it to the next CRLF.

**NOTE:** I have made my code work to my satisfaction, but in the interest of not receiving anymore downvotes (3 at the time of this writing) or getting banned again, I will not post the solution, nor delete the question.  Those are taboo here.  Taking into account the requests for more info from the comments has only earned me downvotes, so I think I'm just stuck in the SO-Catch-22.

Comment: Any particular code that you have written or tried?

Comment: Not yet.  I know I need to use `substring`, but I can't figure out how to calculate the end point for it.  It requires integers, and does not have any matching built into it.

Comment: substring should work perfectly as long as you code a way to calculate the end point. That sounds like another monster to tackle. If the data was a property that might make this possible, but if it is just returning a string of data that you need to parse and it is regularly changing, that sounds like it will need a unique solution

Comment: Do you have a use case example? An help would be infinitely more useful if you provide and example and what you have tried. If you are looking for something but don't know where to start using `.IndexOf()` (this might be the find you are looking for) would help get you the starting point. Or just use regex because it is easier.

Comment: Guys, this is like a textbook-level question.  You're completely overcomplicating it.  I'm trying to pull a MAC address from an embedded system using a telnet-like command.  No, it's not homework.  I think I can make use of `IndexOf()`, which I found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Comment: _Guys, this is like a textbook-level question_.. that is why we are reacting this way because those types of questions are usually already answered somewhere else here.

Comment: I know Stack Overflow hates questions, but I couldn't find a solution, and only found that small lead.  Seems like it should be on a million blogs, but it's not.

Comment: Substring in most cases does not care about the length of the string. You pull from an index and it will pull until the end of the string unless you quantify a number of characters. You would know beforehand if that is an issue since you can query the string length. This is why I wanted to see a use case / example of what you are trying to accomplish because there likely many ways to accomplish this. What does it matter if there is a trailing new line? You can use `.Trim()` to clear it either before or after?

Comment: This works fine ``"This is a string with a trailing newline`n".Substring(20)``. All characters the 19th. I didn't need to specify length.

Comment: "I will not post the solution, nor delete the question." - I cannot find your question helpful, if you are not willing to give back to the community, by answering your own question.  You would gain more far more reputation by answering your own question then adding meta commentary to your question.

Comment: @Security Hound: In my experience, answering my own question leads to more negative attention.  I've even had other SO people tell me that it's a way to get quickly downvoted.  Thanks for the extra downvote BTW.  The meta commentary is the only option: I can't remove my question, I can't answer my own question, and editing it is only going to make it worse, based on past experiences.

Comment: If you didn't realize, these are against SO policies posted on META and what SO users say.  They will also accelerate me towards another ban.

Answer (score 4):

*You could probably have found the first 20 examples in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) outlining this exact same approach, but here goes with PowerShell examples*

If you want to find the index at which CR/LF occurs, use `String.IndexOf()`:

```
PS C:\> "   `r`n".IndexOf("`r`n")
2
```

Use it to calculate the `length` parameter argument for `String.Substring()`:

```
$String = "    This phrase starts at index 4 ends at some point`r`nand then there's more"

# Define the start index
$Offset = 4

# Find the index of the end marker
$CRLFIndex = $string.IndexOf("`r`n")

# Check that the end marker was actually found
if($CRLFIndex -eq -1){
    throw "CRLF not found in string"
}

# Calculate length based on end marker index - start index
$Length = $CRLFIndex - $Offset

# Generate substring
$Substring = $String.Substring($Offset,$Length)
```